# Emerald doesn't work anymore?

Tags: 11.04, emerald

Is Emerald just gone forever for 11.04 users?, does it work with Kubuntu or Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~malteworld/+archive/compiz) for Emerald.

> ppa:malteworld/compiz

Comment: the ppa didn't exist when the question was asked, but nice to know there's one

Answer (score 3):

Emerald hasn't really been maintained for quite a while, and no one has developed a usable replacement as yet.

You may be able to use it on 11.04 on any Desktop (I have not tested with unity btw), but don't expect anything special or stable. In essence **emerald is dead**.

Comment: yeah so i've read in various sites, but at least it worked in 10.10, it doesn't do anything in 11.04.

Comment: In 10.10 the compiz version was 0.8.x, now it's 0.9.x - a complete rewrite :)

Comment: would it be possible to downgrade to 0.8? do i lose something special,? other unity?

Comment: @UriHerrera: You lose unity, and pretty much the ability to use compiz (in other words, you can't downgrade).

Comment: ahh..that's just bad

Answer (score 0):

You can run emerald in 11.04 but you must compile it from source as the version in the official repositories is incompatible with compiz in natty. Check http://cgit.compiz.org/fusion/decorators/emerald/ for the latest head of the source.